# List View above Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to place a linear Layout below a List View in XML and for some reason I get this error

android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

at com.yonivy. ... .onCreate ... .java:37

Here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/content_new" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/editBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/content_edit" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category_activities);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mList); // line 37

    // ...

}
```

If i place the List View as the last child everything works fine for some reason, but that's not how I want it.

Comment: Post your full java code

Comment: project -> clean.........

Comment: it happens for example if You want to start Your apk from eclipse without saving changes....

Comment: My guess is: you copy pasted line 37 to other views and you forget to change the `ListView` cast to `ImageButton`.

Comment: Btw, would this even display that bottom bar, because of that match_parent on listview? Dont you have to set height="0dp" and weight="1" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this before - try cleaning and rebuilding